# Checking if a value is different from any in a given list of values

Tags: javascript, equality-operator

I'm trying to improve an old React web application for work when i stumble upon this variable:

```
const condition = (
  param !== const1 && param !== const2 && param !== const3 && ...
)
```

Is there a best practise to improve this very long and condition?

Comment: Creates an array `[const1, const2, ...]` and calls `includes()`?

Comment: `const condition = ![const1, const2, const3].includes(param);`

Comment: @ynn Ok, i thought i could use includes() only to improve the OR conditions, your solution work as a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way of performing such check if you're checking running the `!==` comparison for all items you should use the `Array.every` functional predicate.

It checks that every item matches the condition:

```js
const condition = [value1, value2, value3].every(value => value !== parameter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten with the array method `includes`.
This will return true if the array has the variable `param`, then use ! to switch the boolean to false:

```
const condition = ![const1, const2, const3, const4].includes(param);
```

Depending on your situation using condition with the ! operator (`!condition`) and declaring without might improve readability:

```
const condition = [const1, const2, const3, const4].includes(param);
```

The declaration above will likelly be my prefered option. However, there are a lot of other ways to achieve this:

In the line below `indexOf` will return -1 when param is not part of the array:

```
const condition = [const1, const2, const3, const4].indexOf(param) === -1;
```

In the line below array method `every` tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value:

```
const condition = [const1, const2, const3, const4].every(value => value !== param)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for your conditions.

```
const conditions = [cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4];
return !condition.includes(conditions)
```

You can also use some

```
const conditions = [cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4];
return conditions.some(item => item !== condition)
```